# Fonts and icons look dull and pixelated on devices with small ppi

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a problem.
On screens with a small ppi (number of pixels per inch), fonts and icons look dull and pixelated. On the second screen on the right, there is another application, but on the same device and everything is ok there (of course, the left side is slightly increased to align the font size, so a bit more pixelation than it is, but still). On screen Samsung Galaxy Tab SM-T531

[image]

I use **xamarin.android**.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardElevation="0.5dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="0.5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"  
        android:padding="1dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"                
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"                      
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:id="@+id/sensorImageView"                        
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="21dp"
            android:text="Caption"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"                       
            android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:text="Description"              
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nameTextView"
            android:id="@+id/descTextView"              
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="21.5dp"
            android:layout_height="21.5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
            android:id="@+id/stateImageView"                         
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="-13.07"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:id="@+id/mainValueTextView"                              
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:text="ob/m"     
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/mainValueSymbolTextView"               
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:text="1`23123"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mainValueTextView"
            android:id="@+id/addValueTextView"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:text="квт/ч"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mainValueTextView"
            android:id="@+id/addValueSymbolTextView"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>   
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Could anyone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Scale-independent Pixels - This is like the dp unit, but it is also scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for both the screen density and the user's preference.

use text size in sp instead dp

That means use `android:textSize="21sp"` instead `android:textSize="21dp"` etc

**scale independent Pixels= sp

**density independent Pixels= dp

Read [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Dimension) for more detailed info